# Windows 10 Ubuntu Dual Boot Issues (I know)

Tags: ubuntu, boot, windows, dual-boot, boot-loader

### Background

I work as a web developer/designer where I use SSH for a LAMP stack so I'm not super familiar with Linux but I'm definitely not a stranger either. Today, mid lecture I decided to check out my boot menu as I planned on installing Ubuntu when I got home (I used Ubuntu in my VM to compile with gcc for a few of my classes and performance is becoming subpar). After fighting with windows 10 for around an hour, I was left locked out and had to reinstall from a USB, which I carry around like an epipen. Once home, I downloaded an Ubuntu 17.10 iso and used rufus to create a Bootable USB. Downloaded Ubuntu no problem, restart after install, cool.

### The Fun Part

Booted straight into Windows. Ooooooooook, so I started doing some research, found out it could've been an issue with GRUB, so I booted from flashdrive and used boot-repair. No dice. Already changed boot priority on UEFI. The partition definitely exists as I viewed it from the flashdrive, but won't show up so I believe I got a bad case of the "Windows rewrites bootmgr on every boot." Tried `sudo efibootmgr -o 0004,0002,2001,0000` with 0004 being the root of my Ubuntu install and 0002 being my flashdrive but no such luck. I used EasyUEFI to disable `\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi` which was a big mistake (I had already changed bootmgr to be grubx64 by that time), and when I restarted my PC had no bootable options, so I booted into my flashdrive and used `sudo efibootmgr -l "\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi"` and booted back into Windows 10 to write this question. Feel free to ask me for more info if anything is unclear, but yes I've disabled Secure Boot as well. I know there are quite a few questions like this but I believe this question is unique in that none of the answered questions I came across were able to solve my problem.

### Pastebin

[link to boot-repair](http://paste.ubuntu.com/26493542)

Answer (score 1):

**Connect to the Internet** then use

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

Go into advanced options and click the Backup and rename Windows EFI files.

IMO this should be left up because every source I found said to use this tool but I don’t recall any mentioning this explicitly.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair